# Get method in prisma return 404

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I'm trying to create a get method to display data from my table in the database.

My model is like this:

```
   model cultivation {
  cultivation_id Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  description    String @db.VarChar(500)
  ec_optimal     Int    @db.SmallInt
  ec_range       Int    @db.SmallInt
  temp_optimal   Int    @db.SmallInt
  temp_range     Int    @db.SmallInt
  ph_optimal     Int    @db.SmallInt
  ph_range       Int    @db.SmallInt
  kit            kit[]
}
```

So i created a file called `CultivationReaderController.ts`

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { prisma } from "../../../shared/database";


export class ReadCultivationController {
  async handled(request:Request, response: Response) {
    // const { id } = request.params;
    try {
      const cultivation = await prisma.cultivation.findMany();
    
      return response.json(cultivation);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json({
        message: "Something went wrong",
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Then I created the `index.js` file and left it like this:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { ReadCultivationController } from "../controllers/CultivationReaderController"

const cultivationRoutes = Router()

const findCultivation = new ReadCultivationController()

cultivationRoutes.get("/cultivation", findCultivation.handled)
```

However when testing in Insomnia the page is not found.
I've tried several ways to create this endpoint but nothing works.
Any ideas on how to go about solving this question?

[image: 404 Not Found]

Comment: Doesn't look like a `prisma` related error. Can you share a minimal reproduction? E.g. the part where `cultivationRoutes` is used seems to be missing.

Comment: Realy!! I was not exporting the route

Answer (score 0):

I was not exporting the route.
Solving:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { CultivationReaderController } from "../controllers/CultivationReaderController"

const cultivationRoutes = Router();

const findCultivation = new CultivationReaderController();

cultivationRoutes.get("/cultivation", findCultivation.handled);

export { cultivationRoutes };
```